# gmaps custom overlay that wipes out all the previous instances

Tags: google-maps

I have created a custom overlay (a marker showing user pictures instead of the default baloon). Basically the  problem I have is that, when adding more than 1 marker to the map, only the last one added is visible. Here's the code:

```
 function FaceMarker(latlng, userUid) {
      console.log("face marker", userUid);
      this._latlng = latlng;
      this._userUid = userUid;
      this._root = document.createElement('div');
      this._root.style.position = 'absolute';
      this._root.style.width = '60px';
      this._root.style.height = '60px';
   }

   FaceMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

   FaceMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = "/thumbs/" + this._userUid + "-60x60.jpg";
      this._root.appendChild(img);
      console.log(this.getPanes().overlayLayer);
      this.getPanes().overlayLayer.appendChild(this._root);
   };

   FaceMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
      var position = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this._latlng);
      var panes = this.getPanes();
      panes.overlayLayer.style.left = position.x - 30 + 'px';
      panes.overlayLayer.style.top = position.y - 120 + 'px';

   };

   FaceMarker.prototype.onRemove = function() {
      this._root.parentNode.removeChild(this._root);
      this._root = null;
   };

   // client code
   var a = new FaceMarker(..., ...);
   var b = new FaceMarker(..., ...);
   a.setMap(myMap); 
   b.setMap(myMap); // only this one will be visible!!!
```

Anyone? I really cannot figure out why the others are not shown.

Ta

Comment: Seems like overkill to use a custom overlay for this. Why not use a custom google maps icon (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Icon) and a regular marker? I realize this doesn't answer your question, but, from your question, it appears you're trying to drive a nail with a sledgehammer.

Comment: Not 100% sure but because of `this._root.style.position = 'absolute';` it seems that you create stack of markers (one over another).